# Why Is My Image Not Recognized In Python?

Tags: python, tkinter

I wrote this code:

```
from tkinter import *
from locate import this_dir

path = str(this_dir())

print(path + "\\BGnew.png")

window = Tk()
window.geometry("480x480")
window.title("CodeHook - Start Menu")
ico = PhotoImage(file = path + "\\icon.png")
bg = PhotoImage(file = path + "\\BGnew.png")

window.iconphoto(True, ico)

c=Canvas(window,bg="gray16",height=200,width=200)
filename=PhotoImage(file= bg)
background_label=Label(window,image=filename)
background_label.place(x=0,y=0,relwidth=1,relheight=1)


new_workspace = Button(window, text = "New Workspace", font = ("", 13))

new_workspace.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

When An Error Occured:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "c:\Users\Dani\Desktop\Code\Python\CodeHook\main.py", line 17, in 
> filename=PhotoImage(file= bg)
> File "C:\Users\Dani\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter_*init*_.py", line 4064, in **init**
> Image.**init**(self, 'photo', name, cnf, master, **kw)
> File "C:\Users\Dani\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter_*init*_.py", line 4009, in **init**
> self.tk.call(('image', 'create', imgtype, name,) + options)
> _tkinter.TclError: couldn't open "pyimage2": no such file or directory

Here Is My Folder Structure:

```
Code

    Python

        CodeHook

            BGnew.png

            icon.png

            main.py (file in which error occured)
```

Python Version: 3.9.7
IDE: Visual Studio Code (User)

Comment: `filename=PhotoImage(file= bg)` The `file=` argument is supposed to be a file path.  `bg` is not a file path.

Comment: @JohnGordon bg is a variable

Comment: Yes it is.  So what?

Comment: ````path```` variable contains the path to the python script, so ````path + "\\BGnew.png"```` is the path + the file name, and that is the bg variable

Comment: No it is not.  `bg = PhotoImage(file = path + "\\BGnew.png")` bg is a PhotoImage object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have a `PhotoImage` object in bg variable.
So you can remove line `filename=PhotoImage(file= bg)` and modify `background_label=Label(window,image=filename)` to `background_label=Label(window,image=bg)`.

Small addition: you can use `os.getcwd()` to get current directory. Also it is a bad practice to concatenate path and filename, you can use `os.path.join()` to do that.

Comment: oh! now i understand it. thank you for the answer!

Comment: i know, but concatenating path and filename is simpler for me. doesn't matter